# Where'd MainMenu.lua go in Civilization 5: Brave New World? I want to enable mods on my Mac!

Tags: steam, civilization-5, macos, civilization-5-brave-new-world

So to unlock Mods on your Mac version of *Civ V*, you need to comment out line 33 of `MainMenu.lua`.  When Gods and Kings came out, `MainMenu.lua` moved, but the fix still worked.  Now that "Brave New World" is out, it appears `MainMenu.lua` has moved again or has just been removed entirely.

Where's `MainMenu.lua` so that I can perform some surgery on it?

Answer (score 3):

On my Mac, it's at the following location:

1. Find the Civ 5 app (`~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Sid Meier's Civilization V/Civilization 5.app`).
2. Right click the app, and select `Show Package Contents`.
3. Navigate to the following folder: `Contents/Home/assets/UI/FrontEnd`
4. `MainMenu.Lua` is in that folder. Looks like the line to comment out is 40 now.

(I haven't tested this, but I've enabled mods before, and this file looks very similar to the old version.)

Comment: Awesome, looks like it worked.  Now to actually put mods in whatever folder they have to be in so I can enable them… ;)

Comment: Alternately just open the Finder, hit ⌘G and paste in `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Sid Meier's Civilization V/Civilization 5.app/Contents/Home/assets/UI/FrontEnd` and you will go right to the folder if you used the standard Steam install.

Answer (score -1):

IT causes that you dont change hidden files to unhidden files, please follow this link to change hidden file to unhidden files>.."

" I hop it works to you  ...

Comment: Please summarize the instructions in the video.  That way, if it ever gets removed, your answer is still valid.